# What and where is the SA Code in Dell laptops?

Tags: dell-inspiron

This evening, I purchased Dell Inspiron 5547 Laptop and there is a Winter Offer going on for 2 years additional warranty. But when i want to do the registration for the same, it asks for Service Tag and SA Code.

I can get the Service Tag from back of Laptop & its Box. But no clue for SA Code.

Can anyone help me to understand what the SA Code is and where I can find it?

Comment: Hi Jason. The obvious question becomes: have you tried calling Dell and asking them?

Answer (score 3):

The offer you are talking about appears to be a special offer [between Dell and their sales partners](http://www.compuindia.com/dell-winteroffer-tnc), :

As the offer clearly states

> For offer eligibility, mandatory registration is required on
>   www.compuindia.com/dellwinteroffer within 7 calendar dates* from the
>   date mentioned on the purchase invoice

I am assuming that you would have read the following:

> - This offer is only valid on Inspiron Notebooks ,Desktops  and Vostro Notebooks  purchases made by individual consumers between 30th
>     December 2014 till 30th  January  2015 across the country.
> - Valid for above mentioned products wherein the Service Tag origin is India.
> - The offer is applicable for any above mentioned products purchased from Authorized sources mentioned below -
>
>   1. Croma & Reliance Outlets
>   2. Multibrand Outlets having a valid **Sales Affiliate Code**.
>   3. www.compuindia.com & www.dell.co.in
>   4. Resellers having a valid Sales Affiliate Code.
> - For offer eligibility, mandatory registration is required on www.compuindia.com/dellwinteroffer within 7 calendar dates* from the date mentioned on the purchase invoice. Registration done post the mentioned period will lead to automatic disqualification. Registration is to be done on behalf of the CX by the Retail Store/Reseller

Essentially your "SA Code" is a code that you should have been supplied by ***the company that sold you the machine*** to prove that they are a valid Dell reseller and that they purchased the machine from Dell and are now selling it on to you.

If you **cannot** get that code from your supplier or were not given it then there is a chance that the whoever you bought it from has claimed the refund already and sold the machine on to you at full price and no way to claim.  With redemption offers you must always read the fine print first and know what you need to get the offer.